# Getting GIT to fully work in TakeCommand

Tags: git, command-line

I am trying to get GIT to work fully in my beloved [TakeCommand command-line window](http://jpsoft.com/) on Windows 7.

I installed msysgit v.1.7.3, created my SSH keys and all, and in GIT Bash, everything works just fine and dandy.

But I always have my TakeCommand windows open anyway - so I really don't want Yet Another Command Line Window just for GIT.

Most commands like `git status`, `git add`, `git commit` and so forth work just fine in TakeCommand - the only thing that doesn't work is pull and push.

I have setup a `~/.ssh/config` file that points to my company's central repo, and in Git Bash, everything works just fine. But in TakeCommand, I get:

```
D:\myGitProject> git pull "origin" master:master
```

> ssh: gerrit: no address associated with name
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

WTF?!?!? Same with `git push` - what's going on here?? My SSH is set up, Git Bash works, the `~/.ssh/config` file is there and accessible - I'm at a loss.....

Any brilliant ideas? I sure hope so!!

**Update:** for @Mark Longair - here's my `~/.ssh/config` file - slightly edited :-)

```
Host gerrit
  Hostname git.mycompany.com
  Port 29418
  User myself
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gerrit_myself_rsa
```

I can ping `git.mycompany.com`, but I cannot ping `gerrit`. Any ideas? Should I add an entry for `gerrit` into my `hosts` file and point it to the same IP as the git server here??

Comment: It looks from the error `no address associated with name` that it's failing to resolve the name `gerrit` to an IP address.  Is `gerrit` an alias defined in your `~/.ssh/config` or something defined in your hosts file?  If it's the former, perhaps you could post your `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question at the end, you could add `gerrit` to your hosts file, but that wouldn't let you customize the port, and doesn't help to understand the problem - specifying a nickname for the host in your SSH config should work!

My suspicion is that the `~/.ssh/config` file isn't being read at all, possibly because SSH is looking in a different location for it.  To test this, just try:

```
ssh gerrit
```

That should just produce the same error.  Then, to get more information, try:

```
ssh -v gerrit
```

If it's working successfully, the output should begin something like the following:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mark/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for gerrit
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.mycompany.com [192.168.0.2] port 22.
[...]
```

(That's from Linux, but it should be similar from the OpenSSH client bundled with msysgit.)  If you don't see the "Reading configuration data [your config file]" line then that's likely to be the problem.

Can you successfully connect with:

```
 ssh myself@git.mycompany.com
```

... incidentally?

The other thing that I would check is what `HOME` is set to at the command prompt.

Comment: As for my HOME - I have `HOMEDRIVE=H:` and `HOMEPATH=\` (those are on one of our servers), and the `.ssh` directory is indeed in `H:\`

Comment: I added the directory where `git.exe` and `ssh.exe` exist to my path, and running `ssh gerrit -v` now gives me:  `ssh: gerrit: no address associated with name`

Comment: @marc_s: how could you run git at all if it wasn't in your PATH?

Comment: @Mark Longair: good question indeed ! Turns out - there was a .cmd file in my path somewhere, which set up some environment variables and then called `git.exe` in the GIT bin directory. Hmm... I wonder what happens if I make sure those env vars already exist before hand..... I'll have to try at the office on Friday - thanks for now!

Comment: @Mark Longair: ok, now that I've added my `c:\bin\git\bin` directory to my path, and I set my `HOME=` and `PLINK_PROTOCOL` environment variables to what GIT expects - everything works just fine right inside TakeCommand ! Not quite clear why it didn't work before - but aynway - it works now - thanks for your help !!

Comment: @marc_s: no problem, it's a quite an honour to answer the top Stack Overflower in Switzerland ;)  (I think I'm 16th)